# Replace text between brackets and carraige returns in Atom.io

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom.io to edit a text transcription of an interview for qualitative analysis.

Here's a sample line:

[30-Aug-19 03:48 PM] Interviewer
See you in 10.

How do I edit it so that it looks like this:

Interviewer: See you in 10.

i.e. remove the text between the square brackets and the square brackets themselves, replace the carriage return with a semi-colon and space.

I have tried looking in the atom manual, tried looking at regex expressions and I can't even begin to get my head round them (not much of a programmer, and not Javascript at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the search & replace with the regex mode

[image]

Activate the regex mode, then search for `\[.*? Interviewer` and replace by `Interviewer:`, it should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I knew about checking the option, but not the syntax. Thanks!